# UWP Different styles for odd and even elements ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, uwp, listboxitem, visualstatemanager

I need a different background for odd and even elements ListBoxItem . I found a code that should solve my problem, but it doesn't want to work in UWP:

```
<Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
</Trigger>
```

Are there any analogues to the property ItemsControl.AlternationIndex, or how can I specify the style of even and odd elements in VisualState?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently in UWP, `ListBox` does not provide related property for setting the background of the alternative rows.

We can create a `CustomListBox` as a derived class of `ListBox` to achieve our needs.

```cs
public class CustomListBox : ListBox
{
    public Brush AlternativeBackground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(AlternativeBackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AlternativeBackgroundProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AlternativeBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AlternativeBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(CustomListBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        var listBoxItem = element as ListBoxItem;
        if (listBoxItem != null)
        {
            var index = IndexFromContainer(element);

            if ((index + 1) % 2 != 1)
            {
                listBoxItem.Background = AlternativeBackground;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```xml
<local:CustomListBox AlternativeBackground="Orange">
    <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Item 4</ListBoxItem>
</local:CustomListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.extensions?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable), which helps you set `AlternateColor` & `AlternateItemTemplate`.
For more info, you can download [Windows Community Toolkit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-community-toolkit-sample-app/9nblggh4tlcq?irgwc=1&OCID=AID2000142_aff_7806_1246483&tduid=%28ir__mspcobhjr0kftn6rxmlij6lydu2xi9r6bani2mt000%29%287806%29%281246483%29%28%28ef8948e453d8b46aebdc80f7bf5c41d9%29%2881561%29%28686431%29%28at106619_a107739_m12_p46057_cHK%29%28%29%29%28ef8948e453d8b46aebdc80f7bf5c41d9%29&irclickid=_mspcobhjr0kftn6rxmlij6lydu2xi9r6bani2mt000&activetab=pivot:overviewtab).

[image]